# What does 'too' mean in "But money he got for that too began to go"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following sentence.

> Then he sold his piano and let the mice live in a bureau drawer. But
>   money he got for that too **began** to go, so he sold the brown suit he wore
>   on Sundays and went on becoming poorer and poorer.

This is from a novel "The Story Of Doctor Dolittle". I am taught that after "too" is adjective like the car is too fast to drive. However "began" is a past tense of "begin", isn't it? What's the meaning of "too began to go"?

Comment: [Too](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too) means _also_ here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mean that "too" means "quite" and "began to go" means "began to be spented"?

Comment: That money also began to run out; his money was almost depleted.

Comment: This sentence has a few grammatical errors, like "*the* brown suit" and "poor*er* and poor*er*."  I would suspect either an incorrect translation/transcription, or that the narrator is speaking in "vernacular".  Vernacular is deliberately incorrect English, to establish someone is rural or uneducated.  As you are referring to a story with talking animals, it could easily be the second.

Comment: Sorry, I transferred incorrectly. What you said is correct. I edited it. Thank you for teaching.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence meaning is muddled by poor punctuation. I had to reread it a few times to gather the meaning. My slightly edited version follows:

> Then he sold his piano and let the mice live in a bureau drawer. But the money he had(?) for that***,*** too***,*** began to go, so he sold the brown suit he wore on Sundays and went on becoming poorer and poorer.

(I added a couple commas)

Here, we can see that "too" is taking its meaning as "as well." The sentence then means:

> Then he sold his piano and let the mice live in a bureau drawer. But the money he had(?) for that **as well** began to go, so he sold the brown suit he wore on Sundays and went on becoming poorer and poorer.

So the money he had for the mice living in the drawer (Not certain what this part is, never read the book myself) began to go *as well as* some other money not mentioned in the sentence.

Comment: @YuuichiTam If this fully answers the question, select this answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark below it. This way, others see it as already answered when browsing questions.

Comment: @EthanChapman -- This is not quite right. Here "got" means **received**. The money he *received* (as a payment for the sold piano) *also* began to *run out* (to be spent, to be used up).